# how to parse search string without fields limit in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

For example:

```
title:lucene+((author:jack)^300.0 (bookname:how to use lucene)^200.0 (price:[100 TO 200])^100.0)~1
```

Is there anyWay parse the lucene query string to Query Object like `Query query = Function(String queryString)` in lucene?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the classic [`QueryParser`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html) to build a parser:

```java
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(default_field_name, analyzer);
```

If you provide field names in your query string (as you do in your example), then the default field name is not used.

The analyzer should typically be the same as the analyzer which was used to build the index. For example, the [`StandardAnalyzer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html):

```java
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
```

And then you can use the string containing your query as follows:

```java
Query query = parser.parse(your_query_string);
```

---

The [demo code](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_3_0/demo/index.html) provided as part of Lucene shows an example of this approach. See lines 118 and 135 in the [SearchFiles.html](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_3_0/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/SearchFiles.html) code.

Comment: thank for you response! There is a word '~1' in the query string. It work nice unless i remove it.   When I set the minimumNumberShouldMatch ,it will  be appended in BooleanQuery.toString().but i have to set the minimumNumberShouldMatch.Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment.

Comment: string = title:lucene+((author:jack)^300.0 (bookname:how to use lucene)^200.0 (price:[100 TO 200])^100.0)~1                                 
             --------------------split line-----------------                                                                                                                  
   there is a '~1' end of the string.It leads to I can't parsed successfully

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Encountered " <FUZZY_SLOP> "~1 "" at line 1, column 177.
Was expecting one of:
    <AND> ...
    <OR> ...
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    ")" ...
    "*" ...
    "^" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <NUMBER> ...
    
 at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.generateParseException(QueryParser.java:999)

Comment: I think you are asking a new question. So you should create a new question where you can explain your new problem fully. (I am very sorry but I am not sure what your comments mean.)